# Configure Visual Studio to select entire hyphenated class names

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

We've decided to follow [@mdo's style guide suggestion about class names](http://codeguide.co/#css-classes) so we have `class` names for elements using dashes, e.g. `my-fancy-btn`, or a full example:

```html
<button class="my-btn my-fancy-btn my-special-btn">GO</button>
```

If I double-click the word `fancy` in that example, only "fancy" gets selected, but I want the entire class name `my-fancy-btn` to be selected.

**How can I configure Visual Studio to select entire class names, even if they're hyphenated?**

I've used my [Google-Fu](https://www.google.nl/search?q=visual%20studio%20double%20click%20select%20entire%20hyphenated%20class) but found nothing but [a UserVoice request for *the opposite* (?)](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/9435474-for-hyphenated-class-names-in-html-double-clickin) as well as instructions for many other types of editors. I've gone through the "Text Editor > HTML" options in Visual Studio but found no relevant setting.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Full Disclaimer:** I wrote this extension.*

I had the same problem, so I went searching and found this question. Good to know I'm not the only one with this problem!

Like you, I couldn't find any settings to enable this, so I ended up writing an extension to do it. You can get it from the Visual Studio gallery, or just search for it within Visual Studio's Extensions and Updates dialog:

[Select Hyphenated](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/335a98ba-7983-4d76-9761-210bce8095bb)

It works with Visual Studio 2015. I see you tagged your question with [visual-studio-2013](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013), so hopefully you're able to upgrade.

Comment: We're certainly able to upgrade, we just haven't yet. Will have to check out your extension on my home PC later. Until then, your answer will in any case be the generic answer to my question: no setting exists, so a custom extension / solution is needed.